PLS-00382: "expression is of wrong type" when opening REF CURSOR on stored procedure called in a loop
I have an outer stored procedure which is calling an inner stored procedure in a loop. The inner stored procedure returns a REF CURSOR consisting of 2 parts, (1) V_SUCCESSFUL_COUNT (2) V_RESPONSE_CODE.
My outer stored procedure is collecting these pairs from all the inner stored procedure calls into the corresponding arrays, V_SUCCESSFUL_COUNTS and V_RESPONSE_CODES. First it opens the inner stored procedure's cursor, fetches the two parts into variables, and then adds those variables to the arrays.
PROCEDURE OUTER_SP(PARAM1, .., P_REF_CURSOR REF CURSOR)
AS
    ..
    V_SUCCESSFUL_COUNT      NUMBER;
    V_RESPONSE_CODE         VARCHAR2(10);
    V_SUCCESSFUL_COUNTS     REF_TYPE_NUM_TABLE := REF_TYPE_NUM_TABLE(); /* Cumulative Successful Counts */
    V_RESPONSE_CODES        REF_VARCHAR2_ARRAY_TABLE := REF_VARCHAR2_ARRAY_TABLE(); /* Cumulative Response Codes */
    V_REF_CURSOR            SYS_REFCURSOR; /* Result from each inner SP */

    FOR i IN 1 .. P_REF_ID_LIST.COUNT LOOP
                    SP_INNER(PARAM1,
                             PARAM2,
                             ...
                             V_REF_CURSOR);

        /* Add V_SUCCESSFUL_COUNT, V_RESPONSE_CODE outputs from this call to collections */
        OPEN V_REF_CURSOR /* Error here! */;
        FETCH V_REF_CURSOR INTO V_SUCCESSFUL_COUNT, V_RESPONSE_CODE;
        V_SUCCESSFUL_COUNTS.EXTEND;
        V_SUCCESSFUL_COUNTS(V_SUCCESSFUL_COUNTS.COUNT) := V_SUCCESSFUL_COUNT;
        V_RESPONSE_CODES.EXTEND;
        V_RESPONSE_CODES(V_RESPONSE_CODES.COUNT) := V_RESPONSE_CODE;
        CLOSE V_REF_CURSOR /* Error here! */;
    END LOOP;

I'm getting this error on the lines
OPEN V_REF_CURSOR / CLOSE V_REF_CURSOR

as I try to retrieve the result from each inner stored procedure call:

PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

It doesn't like me opening the inner stored procedure's cursor before calling FETCH V_REF_CURSOR.
If I remove these OPEN V_REF_CURSOR / CLOSE V_REF_CURSOR lines and go straight to FETCH V_REF_CURSOR, there are no syntax error and the stored procedure compiles, but the results added into the array are incorrect (NULL), as I can see when I run this outer stored procedure.

Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: syntactically valid code (currently you have redacted sections but this make the code syntactically invalid including the BEGIN and END statements for the procedure - please make sure your code will run so that we can replicate the error); also include the relevant CREATE TABLE, CREATE TYPE and INSERT statements for your sample data so that we can run the query and generate output; and the expected output for your sample data. It is very hard to debug something if it cannot be run and we don't know what it should output.

What is P_REF_ID_LIST and SP_INNER?

If you are using a SYS_REFCURSOR data-type then you have probably used OPEN v_ref_cursor FOR ... in SP_INNER, in which case it is syntactically invalid to try to OPEN the cursor again as it is already open.
Remove the OPEN v_refcursor; statement (but not the CLOSE statement) and the code appears to work:
CREATE PACKAGE package_name AS
  TYPE REF_TYPE_NUM_TABLE IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
  TYPE REF_VARCHAR2_ARRAY_TABLE IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1);

  PROCEDURE SP_INNER(
    PARAM1 NUMBER,
    PARAM2 NUMBER,
    V_REF_CURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  );

  PROCEDURE OUTER_SP(
    PARAM1 NUMBER,
    PARAM2 NUMBER,
    P_REF_ID_LIST SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
  );
END;
/

CREATE PACKAGE BODY package_name AS
  PROCEDURE SP_INNER(
    PARAM1 NUMBER,
    PARAM2 NUMBER,
    V_REF_CURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  )
  IS
  BEGIN
    OPEN v_ref_cursor FOR
      SELECT 1, 'A' FROM DUAL;
  END;

  PROCEDURE OUTER_SP(
    PARAM1 NUMBER,
    PARAM2 NUMBER,
    P_REF_ID_LIST SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
  )
  AS
    V_SUCCESSFUL_COUNT      NUMBER;
    V_RESPONSE_CODE         VARCHAR2(10);
    V_SUCCESSFUL_COUNTS     REF_TYPE_NUM_TABLE := REF_TYPE_NUM_TABLE(); /* Cumulative Successful Counts */
    V_RESPONSE_CODES        REF_VARCHAR2_ARRAY_TABLE := REF_VARCHAR2_ARRAY_TABLE(); /* Cumulative Response Codes */
    V_REF_CURSOR            SYS_REFCURSOR; /* Result from each inner SP */
  BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1 .. P_REF_ID_LIST.COUNT LOOP
       SP_INNER(PARAM1, PARAM2, V_REF_CURSOR);
       /* Add V_SUCCESSFUL_COUNT, V_RESPONSE_CODE outputs from this call to collections */
       FETCH V_REF_CURSOR INTO V_SUCCESSFUL_COUNT, V_RESPONSE_CODE;
       V_SUCCESSFUL_COUNTS.EXTEND;
       V_SUCCESSFUL_COUNTS(V_SUCCESSFUL_COUNTS.COUNT) := V_SUCCESSFUL_COUNT;
       V_RESPONSE_CODES.EXTEND;
       V_RESPONSE_CODES(V_RESPONSE_CODES.COUNT) := V_RESPONSE_CODE;
       CLOSE V_REF_CURSOR /* Error here! */;
    END LOOP;

    FOR i IN 1 .. V_SUCCESSFUL_COUNTS.COUNT LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_SUCCESSFUL_COUNTS(i) || ' - ' || V_RESPONSE_CODES(i));
    END LOOP;
  END;
END;
/

Then:
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE();
  package_name.OUTER_SP(3.141, 42, SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(1,2,3));
END;
/

Outputs:
1 - A
1 - A
1 - A

fiddle

Yes, I had to remove those lines and the code does work without them. Thanks

So I do need to keep the CLOSE CURSOR part? Would there be a leak without it? It seems to work without both, from a brief test, but I'm not sure if something would be unsafe about it.

@geneb. When you are done with the cursor then close it. Don't rely on the database always closing cursors. The database generally will close a cursor variable when it goes out of scope but a SYS_REFCURSOR is a handle pointing at the memory location of the cursor and is not actually the cursor variable so it is ALWAYS the responsibility of the caller to ensure they are closed.

I suspect it is SP_INNER that doesn't return anything.
Here's a demo which shows how to do that (if everything goes OK).
This is a query that returns some data; it is used in SP_INNER:
SQL> select ename, sal from emp where deptno = 10;

ENAME             SAL
---------- ----------
CLARK            2450
KING             5000
MILLER           1300

My SP_INNER procedure is really simple; the only "important" thing here is that query used for a ref cursor really returns something:
SQL> create or replace procedure sp_inner(par_rc out sys_refcursor)
  2  is
  3  begin
  4    open par_rc for
  5      select ename, sal from emp where deptno = 10;
  6  end;
  7  /

Procedure created.

SQL> set serveroutput on;

Anonymous PL/SQL block which simulates your OUTER_SP:
SQL> declare
  2    l_rc    sys_refcursor;
  3    l_ename emp.ename%type;
  4    l_sal   emp.sal%type;
  5  begin
  6    sp_inner(l_rc);
  7    loop
  8      fetch l_rc into l_ename, l_sal;
  9      exit when l_rc%notfound;
 10      dbms_output.put_line(l_ename||' - '||l_sal);
 11    end loop;
 12  end;
 13  /
CLARK - 2450
KING - 5000
MILLER - 1300

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>

As you can see, output reflects what select statement itself returns, so - it works.
As you didn't get anything, check what SP_INNER is doing.
Apart from that, for loop uses P_REF_ID_LIST.COUNT but you never said what p_ref_id_list is/contains. If there's nothing there, that loop won't execute at all  so that might be another culprit. Display P_REF_ID_LIST.COUNT value prior to using it in the loop to verify its value.
